# include .NET dll references with the project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

AoA,
  I am trying to make a music player app in wpf C#(Visual Studio 2012, Win 8), I have made a demo(to chk the app on different computer, whether the app is running or not). 4 out of 7 passed, but I cant figure out why my app is not executing on the remaining 3?
6 out of 7 have windows 8 and visual studio 2010 or 2012. One is using windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010(app runs fine on this one)

I cant figure out the problem! There is no error, the app unable to execute on the 3 pc's

Is there a way that I can use my app with the references included? so that there is no need of external 
references?

Any help?

Comment: "There is no error, the app unable to execute" - well what happens when you *try* to execute it? I doubt that you'll persuade many people to download and execute a random piece of code...

Comment: nothing...app doesn't run on click

Comment: @JonSkeet: that's why I wasn't sharing the link...t have removed the link...

Comment: I suggest you create a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the same behaviour. Then you can post the code for this here, and we can have a look.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am ready to share the complete code( if you say so )?

Comment: We don't need the complete code of your whole app - that would be too much to look at. We want a *short* but complete program which shows the same behaviour (in terms of not working).

Comment: @JonSkeet: As I said its a demo, I have a single XAML page with code of nearly 700 lines(with database support). Its hard for me to create another app and check on seven different pc's again. But I am going to try this. Very thanks for your response :)

Comment: Is there anything in the system error log on the machines that failed to start the application?  What are you using as the audio engine?  Reliable audio playback can be very difficult to nail properly.

Comment: @Jammer: Application logs(there is no log of my app there) but I will check on other pc's.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to debug it on one of the machines where your app refuses to run.
If it should be a runtime enviroment issue even if something like user account control (UAC) interferes, u get exceptions. So this doesn't seem to happen, so there must be a flaw in your code. Again, try to debug it on one of those machines. Or programm control of an installed firewall is blockin your app silently in the background...